# GCD for simple download queue

Tags: swift, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

I want to create a simple download queue, i don't need much functionality, just a serial queue so that when i run my download process it will just wait for the first download to finish before starting the second ect.  Im using parse-server which runs its query and get data functions in the background anyway but it seems to run things concurrently.

I was thinking of just using GCD as i don't directly see the need to use create NSURL sessions to download my files when parse-server functionality is handling this.

To this end i have defined a queue:

```
let downloadQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "downloadQueue", qos: .background)
```

And then thought that wrapping my download function in this queue would add the items to be downloaded to the back of the queue.  However this doesn't seem to happen, and files begin downloading as soon as they are selected.

```
func downloadDataToDevice(cell: JourneyCollectionViewCell, selectedIndexPath: IndexPath){

    self.downloadQueue.async {

        // query and progressBlock to track download progress
    }
}
```

Comment: are you calling `downloadDataToDevice` in `cellForRow`?

Comment: `self.downloadQueue.sync` maybe?

Comment: I tried that also.  Same thing.  It might be something to do with how parse runs its queries, but i thought that GCD would not run the code within the block util the other task was complete.

Comment: The problem is that the dispatched code is, itself, asynchronous. You theoretically can use semaphores to make the dispatched block wait for the asynchronous call (tying up a thread in the process), or better use `OperationQueue` instead with custom asynchronous `Operation` subclass. It also opens up the door to using `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to control the degree of concurrency (because you're going to suffer surprising level of performance loss doing the downloads sequentially).

Comment: And in an even more radical departure, if downloading large assets, do your downloads on background `URLSession`, which gets you completely out of dispatch queues or operation queues, and `URLSession` will manage these for you, even after your app terminates, which is incredibly useful when doing many large downloads. Why should the user have to sit there and stare at an app doing the downloads when they could go off and do more productive things with their device. (This is especially useful if doing this in iOS.)

Comment: thanks for the info.  I was hoping not to have to delve into this as it looks complicated. Especially with requirement of updating progress view per item in a collectionview.  so have to look into the delegate methods and see how i can apply them in this case.

Answer (score 1):

### Creating the DispatchQueue

We'll have to go into a bit more detail in order for you to determine the cause of the issue. First, the `dispatchQueue` you created is a `serial` queue. This means any blocks that are added to the queue will be executed in a serial fashion. GCD makes no guarantee over the timing of these executions, only the order in which they are executed. Keep in mind that GCD does not specify what thread your code is going to be executed on, only that it will treat the quality of service as `.background`.

### Adding Blocks

Now, when adding blocks of code to your serial queue, you call either the `.sync` or the `.async` methods on the queue. These classifiers do determine whether or not the block of code you are adding to the queue will be executed sync or async relative to the current thread. So if you add a block of code `.sync` to the queue, GCD will block the **current thread** until the code executed. If you add a block of code `.async` to the queue, then the current thread will continue executing under the discretion of GCD. The `DispatchQueue` itself is still a serial queue whether or not you add a block of code `.sync` or `.async` to it.

### Executing Blocks

Now on to your Parse code, because this is where is can get slightly tricky. We have established that your `DispatchQueue` is a `serial` queue. However, let's say that you add a block of code to the queue that does something in the background (like download a file) and has some callback function. From the point of view of the `DispatchQueue` and the thread that the block of code is running on, as soon as you initiate the background action, this block of code has finished execution, and it will move on to the next block in the queue. Here's an example to clarify a bit:

```
downloadQueue.async {
    Parse.doSomethingAsync("something", callback: {(error: Error) in
        // Do something else ...
    }
}
```

As you can see here, when GCD executes this block of code, the doSomethingAsync method will run the background depending on how the Parse API has implemented the method. If I am not mistaken, the parse API has different functions for either sync or async behavior. As soon as `doSomethingAsync` is called and begins execution in the background, this block of code has finished execution and GCD can then begin executing the next block of code ... even though from your point of view the code is not yet finished, because the file is not done downloading.
The following code does not suffer from this issue:

```
downloadQueue.async {
    Parse.doSomethingSync("something", callback: {(error: Error) in
        // Do something else ...
    }
}
```

Becuase the `doSomethingSync` will execute the action on the current thread relative to the block and the block will halt execution until it is completed executing the `doSomethingSync` method.

### TLDR and More Info

TLDR; You need to make sure the download action in the GCD blocks are serial and will block execution while the download is occuring.

This tutorial goes into a bit more detail on GCD: https://www.raywenderlich.com/60749/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-1

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Think i might have to go the url session method though as it seems to tie up the thread using parse query without the background blocks.